# Jquery/Ajax Request replace empty array in Json feed

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to identify some empty array in my json and place a div instead. At the moment when the script sees empty array it stops load json. The code is:

```
$.each(data.posts, function (i, item) {
    var newstitle = item.title;
    var newstmbn = item.thumbnail;

    if (data !== undefined && data.posts !== undefined && data.posts.attachments !== undefined) {
        $.each(item.attachments, function (i2, type) {
            $('#news').append('<div>' + item.thumbnail + '</div>');
        });
    } else {
        $.each(item.attachments, function (i2, type) {
            $('#news').append('<div>' + type.images.thumbnail.url + '</div>');
        });
    }
    output.append(news);

});
```

My json looks like:

```
{
    "posts": [
    {
        "id": 914,
        "title": "post1",
        "thumbnail": "\/uploads\/url.jpeg",
        "attachments": [
        {
            "images": {
                "thumbnail": {
                    "url": "\/uploads\/url-150x92.jpeg"
                }
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 915,
        "title": "post1",
        "thumbnail": "\/uploads\/url.jpeg",
        "attachments": []
    },
    {
        "id": 914,
        "title": "post1",
        "thumbnail": "\/uploads\/url.jpeg",
        "attachments": [
        {
            "images": {
                "thumbnail": {
                    "url": "\/uploads\/url-150x99.jpeg"
                }
            }
        }
        ]
    }
]}
```

So you can see some "attachments" are empty and I want to place "item.thumbnail" instead but it doesn't seem working. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main problem is this line:

```
 if (data !== undefined && data.posts !== undefined && data.posts.attachments !== undefined)
```

This is placed inside the .each loop iterating over the `data.posts` array.

```
if (data !== undefined && data.posts !== undefined)
```

should be placed outside of that loop, to test if looping will even be possible.

```
data.posts.attachments !== undefined
```

doesn't make any sense, as data.posts is an array and as such has no attachments property. That should instead be

```
if(item.attachments !== undefined)
```

If this is false, i.e. the item has no attachments, you can't iterate over item.attachments like you are currently doing. Also, you have gotten the if/else the wrong way around, so replace

```
$.each(item.attachments, function (i2, type) {
    $('#news').append('<div>' + type.images.thumbnail.url + '</div>');
});
```

with

```
$('#news').append('<div>' + item.thumbnail + '</div>');
```

and

```
$.each(item.attachments, function (i2, type) {
    $('#news').append('<div>' + item.thumbnail + '</div>');
});
```

with

```
$.each(item.attachments, function (i2, type) {
    $('#news').append('<div>' + type.images.thumbnail.url + '</div>');
});
```

Edit: since I realize the above may be hard to follow, here comes what I believe is the correct code:

```
if (data !== undefined && data.posts !== undefined) {
    $.each(data.posts, function (i, item) {
        if (item.attachments !== undefined && item.attachments.length > 0) {
            $.each(item.attachments, function (i2, type) {
                $('#news').append('<div>' + type.images.thumbnail.url + '</div>');
            });
        } else {
            $('#news').append('<div>' + item.thumbnail + '</div>');
        }
        output.append(news); //I assume output is a valid jquery object...
    });
}
```

Proof of concept at http://jsfiddle.net/Jh3hk/

Comment: Sorry Peter, I am not guru in jquery and cannot get it. Can you please explain a bit more....

Comment: Thank you Peter, the problem only with displaying "item.thumbnail" instead of "attachments" when they are empty...I have added your line and when attachments are empty it just doesn't show anything...And when the attachments exists it shows the image...

Comment: Please check the fiddle I linked, it uses the exact same code as above, except I replaced `output` with `$('body')` and it seems to be working fine.